# How to handle maximum participants count safely?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

We have:

- a table `Room`
- a table `Person`
- an intermediary table `PersonRoom`

in `Room` i have a *maximum* of `Person` which corresponds to the maximum of persons that can go in the room.
Like this:

```
Room
  id
  maximum_persons
Person
  id
  name
PersonRoom
  id
  room_id
  person_id
```

Each time a person with "`my_person_id`" wants to go into a room with "`my_room_id`", I should do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO PersonRoom (room_id, person_id)
                VALUES (my_room_id, my_person_id)
```

But *I should not be able to insert a person if the room is full* ie I should do something like (I know that *this is not valid SQL*):

```
@TOTAL = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PersonRoom
         WHERE room_id = my_room_id;
IF @TOTAL < (SELECT maximum_persons) FROM Room WHERE id = my_room_id:
    INSERT INTO PersonRoom (room_id, person_id)
                    VALUES (my_room_id, my_person_id)
```

I'd like to handle this on the Database side

- Is there a solution for SQLite? If not, is there a solution for PostgreSQL
- What would be the SQL?
- If I do this in **one transaction**, will it be 100% safe if there are many people who try to register at the same time for the same room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak for PostgreSQL.

There are two solutions:

1. Run the `SELECT` and the `INSERT` in one transaction and lock the table `personroom` before you do the `SELECT`.

   You need `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock mode, which means that all such operations are serialized. This is bad for concurrency, but simple and safe.
2. Run the `SELECT` and the `INSERT` in one `SERIALIZABLE` transaction.

   This will allow concurrent modifications, but still prevent anything that would be impossible in a serialized execution order. If there is a conflict, one of the transactions will receive a *serialization error* and has to retry the transaction.

Comment: Do you think I may be able to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update to apply your #2 solution?

Comment: No, that won't help. It would be similar to my first solution, but the lock taken is not strong enough to block readers.

Comment: I checked your answer as valid because its a source of inspiration and I've made my code based on this. I've asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484638/how-to-add-new-player-safely to know if my code is safe, but no answer....

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, you can prevent this with a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html):

```
CREATE TRIGGER max_persons_check
BEFORE INSERT ON PersonRoom
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PersonRoom WHERE room_id = NEW.room_id)
  >= (SELECT maximum_persons FROM Room WHERE id = NEW.room_id)
BEGIN
  SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "too many persons in this room");
END;
```

Or just do the query to check this in your code. (In SQLite, all transactions are serializable.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, do you think there's a possibility to make this compatible for bot SQLite and PostgreSQL?

Comment: No; SQLite's and PostgreSQL's triggers are incompatible.

Comment: So I guess I'll have to make my own transaction and use the #2 solution of @Laurenz Albe (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/)

Comment: ... or use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update to make an access exclusive to the tabke

Comment: That solution cannot be right unless readers block other readers in SQLite. Otherwise two concurrent transactions can both run the trigger at the same time, find the condition satisfied and proceed to modify the table.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe As I said, SQLite transactions are serializable. This is implemented with a global lock on the entire database.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Then your solution is correct of course.